# Checking if pointer is greater than 0?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to determine the purpose of checking for a pointer being greater than 0:

```
void someFunction(int *src) {
   int val = *src++;
   if( val > 0 ) {
       // Do something?
   }
}
```

If the data type is pointer, wouldn't the value of the pointer always be a memory address? Does doing pointer arithmetic do something that may set val = 0 ?

Is this a simple null pointer check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not checking if a pointer is greater than zero; it's checking if the pointed-to value is greater than zero, and simultaneously advancing the pointer by one. Here's some equivalent code that might help you understand:

```
void someFunction(int *src) {
   int val = *src; // Dereferencing the pointer
   src++;          // Moving the pointer

   if( val > 0 ) {
       // Do something?
   }
}
```

`val` is just an `int`, not a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

`val` *isn't* a pointer; it's an `int`, and its value is obtained by dereferencing `src`.

Answer (score 4):

You're not checking if the pointer is > 0, you are checking if the value held in the location pointed to is greater than 0. `src` alone would be an address, `*src` is the value held at that address.

Answer (score 3):

That's not checking a pointer, it's checking an integer.  The `*` operator *dereferences* the pointer, yielding the value the pointer is currently pointing at.  For example, if `src` is pointing at a `0`, `val` will be `0` and the condition of that `if` statement will be false.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the line that’s giving you trouble:

```
int val = *src++;
```

You ought to recognize that as the postfix increment operator at work, so we can split that line in two:

```
int val = *src;
++src;
```

At this point, `val` has a copy of the value `src` *pointed to* at function’s start; meanwhile `src` itself now points to the next memory location.

There is nothing here that checks whether the pointer `src` is null, and its nullness (or otherwise) has no bearing on what value is stored in `val`.